# CodeMirror content shift

Tags: codemirror

I am using CodeMirror (version 2, the latest Jan 2012 release), in my project. On $(document)ready, the code is loaded in the CodeMirror.

Sometimes, the initial view of the CodeMirror window is shifted entirely to the right. Here is an illustration:

http://www.sqlanswers.com/CodeMirrorIssue.gif

The image shows how the entire CodeMirror content is outside of CodeMirror-lines DIV. Once I perform any action inside the code editor (e.i. type a character), the entire content snaps into place and all is good. I tested this in Chrome, IE 9 and Safari, and in all browser, I see this problem.

Calling .refresh and .focus doesn't seem to help.

Does anybody know what may be causing this occasional shifts of content outside of the CodeMirror-lines DIV?

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted quite a while ago, But I was able to solve this issue by removing the css "border" property in `.CodeMirror { }`